# Online Document editing in J2EE based web applications with OnlyOffice- But callback Url is not working

Tags: angularjs, document, editing, onlyoffice

We are working on a Web application with angularJS and using spring/hibernate.
We are using Linux operating system in production environment and Development environment is Windows.We are trying implement online document editing tool like ms-word in our application.

After some research we are using OnlyOffice https://api.onlyoffice.com/ .
I am using the following angularJs component to use onlyOffice
https://github.com/legalthings/angular-onlyoffice
We are able to integrate it with the application and we can see the opened document in the editor in web browser.
But my changes are not being saved.The control is not reaching the callBackUrl.

Since angularJs component uses onSave method which is not there in OnlyOffice API anymore.So i have changed the code in html and JS file a bit:-
HTML file code is:-

```
<div ng-controller="DocumentEditController">
  <onlyoffice-editor src="{{ trustSrc(document.src) }}"
                     title="{{ document.name }}">
  </onlyoffice-editor>
</div>
```

And JS file code is:-

```
angular.module('onlyoffice', []);

 angular.module('onlyoffice').directive('onlyofficeEditor', [function () {
 function key(k) {
 var result = k.replace(new RegExp("[^0-9-.a-zA-Z_=]", "g"), "_") + (new                                           

 Date()).getTime();
 return result.substring(result.length - Math.min(result.length, 50));
 }

 var getDocumentType = function (ext) {
 if (".docx.doc.odt.rtf.txt.html.htm.mht.pdf.djvu.fb2.epub.xps".indexOf(ext)             != -1) return "text";
if (".xls.xlsx.ods.csv".indexOf(ext) != -1) return "spreadsheet";
if (".pps.ppsx.ppt.pptx.odp".indexOf(ext) != -1) return "presentation";
return null;
};

return {
template: '<div id="onlyoffice-editor"></div>',

link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $attrs.src;
  }, function () {
    if (!$attrs.src) return;
    var docUrl = $attrs.src;
    var docTitle = $attrs.title || docUrl;
    var docKey = key(docUrl);
    var docType = docUrl.split('?')[0].substring(docUrl.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).trim().toLowerCase();
    var documentType = getDocumentType(docType);

    var config = {
      type: "desktop",
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      documentType: documentType,
      document: {
        title: docTitle,
        url: docUrl,
        fileType: docType,
        key: docKey,
        permissions: {
          edit: true,
          download: false
        }
      },
      editorConfig: {
        mode: 'edit',
        callbackUrl:"/documentSave"
      },
      events: {
        onReady: function () {alert("in on ready");
          setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
              $scope.ready = true;
            });
          }, 5000);
        },

        onError: function (event) {
            alert(event.data);
          //  var url = event.data;
           // $scope.save({url: url, close: $scope.close});
          },
        }
    };

    //creating object editing
    new DocsAPI.DocEditor("onlyoffice-editor", config);
  });
}
 }
 }]);
```

I changed the documenSave to the fully qualified name using localhost and appname also but that is also not working.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit

CallBackUrl is being called now on close of browser button...But our requirement is to save the document on click of save button. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that clicking on the "Save" button creates a temp file in the document editor. The working document version will only be created after closing the document editor by all users (in ten seconds).
It is impossible to download the changed document in real time (before closing it).